# Adding HTML snippets in the blade-view

Tags: php, laravel, project

I'm creating laravel project with my custom js player. It is already done and working, so i need to display divs with songs on the page and i don't know what is the best practice for doing that.

What i tried:
I have a Song model where i've added methods for displaying songs.

```
{
  static public function displaySongs()
  {
    $songs = Song::all();
    echo "<div class='ostContainer'>";
    foreach ($songs as $song) {
      $song->displayOne();
    }
    echo "<div>";
    return $songs;
  }

  public function displayOne()
  {
    $songname = substr($this->name, 0, -4);
    echo "<div class='songContainer noselect' 
            data-audio='$this->path$this->name' 
            data-songid='$this->id'
            data-songname='$songname'>$songname</div>";
  }
}
```

And the blade view:

```
@extends('layout.layout')
@section('content')
    <audio id="audio"></audio>
    @include('player._playercontainer')
    <?php App\Song::displaySongs() ?>
@endsection
```

This works perfectly as intended, but i feel like this code is wrong.
Is there a better way to go about this?

Laravel version: 5.8.*.

Comment: Use `blade` syntax. Instead of `<?php ?>`, use `{{ }}`, or, since the return is `html`, use `{!! !!}`. Generally you don't query stuff in the view directly, but I think using a static method like that is alright. Or wait; hold that thought. In your `displaySongs()` and `displayOne()`, you'd have to append the html to a string then return that string for the `{!! App\Song::displaySongs() !!}` to work.

Comment: A better practice would be using blade, please review this link:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade,

Comment: @TimLewis I am aware of this syntax, but I didn't want to bother with it since it doesn't really improve much there. I will most likely go with what symlink suggested.

Comment: Yup; that's fair. There are instances when you would want to have the code in the model (mainly for reusability), but that could also be done with `blade` components (`@include("component")`, etc.) Lots of different approaches; go with what works for you, but also what's appropriate for the framework you're using. Cheers!

Comment: @TimLewis I use that approach in another view, my code is all over the place right now, because I'm new to creating web-apps and laravel, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do most of this in your view. Do something like:

```
public function displaySongs()
{
    return view('songs')->with([
        'songs' => Song::all()
    ]);
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@extends('layout.layout')
@section('content')
    <audio id="audio"></audio>
    @include('player._playercontainer')
    <div class='ostContainer'>
        @foreach ($songs as $song)
            @php
                $songname = substr($song->name, 0, -4);
            @endphp
            <div class='songContainer noselect' 
                data-audio='{{$song->path}}{{$song->name}}' 
                data-songid='{{$song->id}}'
                data-songname='{{$songname}}'>
                {{$songname}}
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endsection
```

As a general rule, you want your logic in your model, skinny controllers, and all of the HTML in your view. In this instance though, the logic is simple enough that you can just set a single variable in your view on the fly.

Comment: Yeah, that's how it initially was, but I wanted something compact in a view, because if I would want to use that logic in another view that is more code to copy instead of one call. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexIsaev You're welcome. If you want to reuse the code in other views, you can put it in a partial and `@include` it wherever you want. You'll have to remember what object to pass it, but it's generally better practice than putting HTML in your models or controllers.

Comment: I use `@include` for displaying playlists, but just as with my approach with displaying songs I wasn't sure if i that was correct. I will use it then, thanks.